# Update query doesn't make changes on database in transaction

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have problem to determine what is wrong.

My application update some data for object in loop, so at the end each loop I want to update date of changes.

```
<?php
    $arrAccounts = $adminRepository->findAll();
    #array that pass to render
    $arrOutputs = [];


    $i =0;
    $sum = count($arrAccounts);

    while ($i < $sum ){
        $currAccount = $arrAccounts[$i];
        $arrOutputs[] = $currAccount->getName();


        $loopTime = 3600;
                
        $strDateTimeFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
        $currentDT = new \DateTime('NOW');
        
        $startTimeDT = new \DateTime($currAccount->getUpdateDate()->format($strDateTimeFormat));
        $endTimeDT = new \DateTime();
        $endTimeDT->setTimestamp( ( $startTimeDT->getTimestamp())+$loopTime);

        $intCycles = floor ( ( ( $currentDT->getTimestamp() - $startTimeDT->getTimestamp())/$loopTime ) );

        $arrOutputs[] = 'loops: '.$intCycles;

        $startTime = $startTimeDT->format($strDateTimeFormat);

        if ( $endTimeDT->getTimestamp() > $currentDT->getTimestamp()  ) {
            $endTimeDT->setTimestamp( $currentDT->getTimestamp() );
        }


        $j=0;
        while($j <= $intCycles){

            $arrOutputs[] = 'Loop:'.$j;
            $arrOutputs[] = $startTimeDT->format($strDateTimeFormat).':'.$endTimeDT->format($strDateTimeFormat);

            $arrAccounts[$i]->setUpdateDate($endTimeDT);
            $entityManager->persist($currAccount);
            $arrOutputs[] = 'setUpdateDate:'.$endTimeDT->format($strDateTimeFormat);
            $entityManager->flush();

  
            /*
            $sql = "UPDATE table SET UpdateDate = '".$endTimeDT->format($strDateTimeFormat)."' WHERE id = ".$currAccount->getId();
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            */

            $startTimeDT->setTimestamp($endTimeDT->getTimestamp() );
            $endTimeDT->setTimestamp($endTimeDT->getTimestamp() + $loopTime );
            
            if ( $endTimeDT->getTimestamp() > $currentDT->getTimestamp()  ) {
                $endTimeDT->setTimestamp( $currentDT->getTimestamp() );
            }


            
            $j++;
        }
        $i++;
    }
  ?>
```

In panel db in symfony I see

```
2   0.48 ms 
"START TRANSACTION"
Parameters:
[]
View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
3   4.29 ms 
UPDATE table SET update_date = ? WHERE id = ?
Parameters:
[▼
  "2020-07-19 12:10:53"
  1
]
View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
4   2.13 ms 
"COMMIT"
Parameters:
[]
View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
5   0.37 ms 
"START TRANSACTION"
Parameters:
[]
View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
6   0.91 ms 
UPDATE table SET update_date = ? WHERE id = ?
Parameters:
[▼
  "2020-07-19 12:10:53"
  2
]
View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
7   2.05 ms 
"COMMIT"
Parameters:
[]
View formatted query    View runnable query    Explain query
```

In output render

```
output lines
Account1
loops: 5
Loop:0
2020-07-19 06:59:24:2020-07-19 07:59:24
setUpdateDate:2020-07-19 07:59:24
Loop:1
2020-07-19 07:59:24:2020-07-19 08:59:24
setUpdateDate:2020-07-19 08:59:24
Loop:2
2020-07-19 08:59:24:2020-07-19 09:59:24
setUpdateDate:2020-07-19 09:59:24
Loop:3
2020-07-19 09:59:24:2020-07-19 10:59:24
setUpdateDate:2020-07-19 10:59:24
Loop:4
2020-07-19 10:59:24:2020-07-19 11:59:24
setUpdateDate:2020-07-19 11:59:24
Loop:5
2020-07-19 11:59:24:2020-07-19 12:10:53
setUpdateDate:2020-07-19 12:10:53
Account2
loops: 3
Loop:0
2020-07-19 09:00:17:2020-07-19 10:00:17
setUpdateDate:2020-07-19 10:00:17
Loop:1
2020-07-19 10:00:17:2020-07-19 11:00:17
setUpdateDate:2020-07-19 11:00:17
Loop:2
2020-07-19 11:00:17:2020-07-19 12:00:17
setUpdateDate:2020-07-19 12:00:17
Loop:3
2020-07-19 12:00:17:2020-07-19 12:10:53
setUpdateDate:2020-07-19 12:10:53
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without the current and the expected results, everyone else will also have a hard time to determine what is wrong. Showing code is good, but when possible try to give a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: please show more of your code, because so far, it's completely unclear where $myObject, $dateTimeObject, and all the other vars come from. it could very well be, that you set the same value over and over again. Then there would indeed only be one update, because why would you update an unchanged entity? so please expand your code so that we can somewhat get a minimal complete and verifiable example as jowey asked.

Comment: yes, i understand, but I comment out all lines that can change $myObject, i thought about it that i change date in other line/other part of code, but i have only one transaction with the end of update DATE TIME without previous changes. I didn't see any other update althought in my output i see each loop and when I use RAW SQL i see any change when i refresh database during LOAD DATA

Comment: any idea in problem ? I typed full data about this issue

Answer (score 0):

First, you **persist** all your objects , then you **flush** at the end.

```
  while($i < $allObjects){
        $j=0;
        while($j <= $someNumberOfCycles){
            // some operation to get your object $myObject
            $myObject->setUpdateDate($dateTimeObject);
            $entityManager->persist($myObject);
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $entityManager->flush();
```